# slideToggle not working for me

Tags: php, jquery, html, slidetoggle

Im trying to make a left side navigation that slides down with sub categories when you click on one of the links.

I've got it to work for the top link only but the others dont work.

In my header file I have some jquery script like this:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>
```

in my HTML/PHP i have this code:

```
    <div id="left-prod-nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="top">Product Categories</li>
            <?for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) 
            {?> 
            <div id="flip"><li><img src="images/arrowright_off.gif" style="padding:0px; margin:0px;float:right;"><a href="#"><?=$result[$i]['categoryName']?></a></li> </div>
            <div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
            <?}?>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
```

so the navigation is there...and when I click on the top one, the others slide down so you can see the sub categories for the one I clicked.

however if I click any of the others nothing happens.

has anyone had this problem before or know how to solve it looking at my code?

Thanks

Comment: ID's should be unique...your loop is going to append multiple div's with matching ID's

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: ok, how do i pass unique IDs into the jquery?

Comment: you can also just use a class for both divs then do `$(this).next('.panel')` - or else you'll be manually writing each unique ID in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can assume you are trying to accomplish something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/QQRy8/

```
$(".flip").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

I changed your jQuery to use classes, you should change your PHP to give each div a class name instead of an ID (ID's must be unique!)

This answer is based off this HTML:

```
<div class="flip">
    <li>
        <a href="#">cool</a>
    </li> 
</div>

<div class="panel" style="display: none;">Hello world!</div>
```

Comment: thats exactly what i want to do. I used your example but now all the panels are showing straight away and clicking the links just hides them, clicking them again doesnt even re-show them...here is my new jquery code....."<script> 
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".flip").click(function(){
      $(this).next(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
 });
</script>"...here is my new html...."<div class="flip"><li><img src="images/arrowright_off.gif" style="padding:0px; margin:0px;float:right;"><a href="#"><?=$result[$i]['categoryName']?></a></li> </div>
     <div class="panel">Hello world!</div>"

Comment: never mind...its done now just a tweak of the CSS...thanks for your answer it worked perfect